# Button onPress not printing console log in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, button

In Below code am unable to understand why onPress function is not getting called and thereby not printing anything on console.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

import { Button, Text } from 'react-native'
const stack1 = createStackNavigator()
const stack2 = createStackNavigator()
function buttonPressed(){
  console.log("TarunD screen1")
}
const screen1 = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Text>
        Hello Screen1
      </Text>
      <Button 
        title="screen1 button"
        onPress={buttonPressed}
      />
    </>
  )
}

const screen2 = ()=>{
  return (
    <Text>
      Hello Screen2
    </Text>
  )
}
const App = () => {
  console.log("Hello App")
  return (  
  <NavigationContainer>
    <stack1.Navigator>
      <stack1.Screen name="Screen1" component={screen1}/>
    </stack1.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>)

}

export default App
```

Basically defined onPress and a button.
Am just trying to print console logs in the button, do you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

define `buttonPressed` as a callback function

```
const buttonPressed = () => {
  console.log("TarunD screen1")
}
```

Comment: why normal function did not worked? can you please help in elaborating it a little more?